# Is it possible to customize your desktop through the electron framework?

Tags: electron

I'm working on a project in which the user will be able to change windows app icons through an application. Is it possible to have electron perform such a task or is it impossible for the electron framework to actually communicate with windows like that?

Answer (score -1):

**I sadly can't proof that but**

I think it is possible. You could for example use [Child Process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) and spawn processes that do things for you or write your own c/c++ modules. You can actually write c/c++ node functions, classes and so on, wrap them and use them in nodejs. Here to the [Reference](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html). Be aware though, if you don't find any pre-made solutions you have to do that for every operating system individual!